# How to work with block in loop by using sed?

Tags: loops, sed, block

I have file with some blocks, like this:

```
<start> test var=3333
<g>test=000000000000 tst <s>
<end>
...
<start> var=564735628
<title>somethink<\title>
<end>
...
```

And I need to get block between  and  sections in a loop. 
And then I need to get some simbols in the current block.
I try to do like this:

```
for block in $(cat $file | sed -n '/<start>/,/<end>/p;'); do
         echo $block 
done
```

Result is:

```
<start>
```

instead

```
<start> test 1
<g>test=000000000000 tst <s>
<end>
```

How can I get the entire block for further processing?

---

Ok, I try to explain
Source is

```
<start> test var=3333
<g>test=000000000000 tst <s>
<end>
```

Result of yours code is not a block. It is just a sting.
The string is `<end>t> test var=3333tst <s>`
As can you see it is overlaping strings of the block on each other.

Answer (score 1):

One sugession, do not used `sed` here. 
Use languages like `perl` or `python` which gives modules for parsing `HTML` and `XML`.

Comment: This could possibly not be XML compatible, because the block ends with `<end>` and not `</start>`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
block=""
cat $file | sed -n '/<start>/,/<end>/p;' | while read -r line; do
     if [ -z "$block" ]; then
         block="$line"
     else
         block=$(printf "%s\\n%s" "$block" "$line")
     fi

     if printf "%s\\n" "$line" | grep "<end>" > /dev/null; then
         echo "$block"
         block=""
     fi
done
```

As *choroba* said in his answer, your for loop will use the IFS variable to split sed's output into separate fields, and the block variable will contain only a single field. (Ie., block will contain `<start>`, then `test`, then `var=3333`, and so on).

A solution is to force it read line by line, by piping the output of sed into the loop command, and read the line using the `read` command. The `-r` flag for the read command forces it not to interpret the backslash as an escaping character. Now we have a variable `$line` with our line, but not the block. To get the block, simply concatenate the lines together until we find the `<end>` string.

If the `$block` variable is empty, we can simply assign the `$line` to it. Otherwise, we use the `printf` command to generate a new string containing the previous value of `$block` concatanated with a newline character and the contents of `$line`. This newline character prevents that the block will become a single line.

To test if we found the last line, we can print the current value of the block and see if grep finds it. I used printf because it's safer then echo when the string we want to print starts with a variable (we can't guarantee that the variable doesn't start with a hyphen, which echo could interpret as an option). We must also remember to clear the block variable when we actually find a block, in order to prepare it for the next block.

Comment: The result is very strange. Obtain not block a row in which all lines in the block, that is, overlap one line to another. Somethink like this:
`<endrt> test var=3333st <s>`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understood your comment. You're saying that lines are getting mixed together in the output? What are using as input? Is it the result of a command, or is there a test file? Could you possibly post a block that can reproduce the problem, please? I also made a minor change, adding the '-r' flag to the read command, because the backslashes were being interpreted as escape characters. Don't know if this is related to the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Ok, I try to explain
Source is 

    `<start> test var=3333
    <g>test=000000000000 tst <s>
    <end>`

Result of yours code is not a block. It is just a sting.
The result's string is `<end>t> test var=3333tst <s>`
As can you see it is overlaping strings of the block on each other.

Comment: And I have one more restriction. I use busybox interpretator in fact. Where I can't work with arrays.

Comment: I don't know how bash-compatible busybox is. Therefore, I'll edit the line `block="$block$line"$'\n'` in order to remove ANSI C quoting, which is a bash feature.

Comment: The last one is perfect! Everything works fine. Thank you so much for your help. It worked!

Comment: You're welcome =) If you don't mind, could you consider up-voting or accepting an answer, please? Thank you very much =)

Answer (score 0):

Word splitting is applied to the output of your `sed` command. You can set IFS to an empty value to prevent word splitting on the `sed` output, but it will make the whole output of `sed` into one "block". I would rather switch to a more powerful language like Perl.

Comment: Hurried unfortunately
instead of one block in the loop returns the entire file
What to do?

Comment: Sorry, IFS cannot be a string in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
OIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; block=($(sed '/<start>/,/<end>/!d' file)); IFS=$OIFS
for x in "${!block[@]}"; do echo "${block[x]}"; done
```

Slurp the sed command output into an array `block` and loop through the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I got the busybox, where array does not support.

Answer (score 0):

By changing IFS and inserting a delimiter character in between your blocks, you can iterate through each block.

For example, use `:` as the delimiter

```
OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=':'
blocks=$(sed -n '/start/,/end/ {/start/ s/^/:/; p}' file)
for block in ${blocks#:}; do
  echo "This is block $((count++))"
  echo "$block"
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Note:

1. Blocks are 'separated' by inserting `:` before `<start>` and setting `IFS` to `:`
2. `${blocks#:}` removes the first `:`, otherwise `:block1:block2...` is interpreted as `emptyblock:block1:block2...`, i.e. the loop iterates over the non-existent first block (which is empty and exists due to how `:` is placed)
3. Alternatively, `:` can be placed behind `<end>` but then the last line of the block would become `<end>:\n` so there would be an extra newline before the start of next block.